# socket error on py2neo (neo4j) when setting up

Tags: python, iis, neo4j, port, py2neo

I've simply installed py2neo on 2.7.3 set up the next code and get the following exception:

```
from py2neo import neo4j
from py2neo import node, rel
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
print (graph_db.neo4j_version)
```

and i get hit by this every time:

```
py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: unknown error
```

iis is working and ports 1337 and 7474 are not in use according to netstat -a and -an

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned IIS then I presume you're running on Windows. I use Linux exclusively to build and test py2neo so my environment is quite different. I've found out recently that MacOS generates different network error codes to those I have catered for on Linux and would assume that Windows introduces further challenges.

While I can't debug this for you, if you're able to diagnose a networking issue with py2neo and produce a patch, I'll be happy to apply it.

Comment: I checked my ports and 7474 and 1337 are not in use :/ could it be that py2neo doesn't work at win 7?

Comment: If port 7474 is not running then either the Neo4j server is not running or you have configured an alternative port. I don't know what you would be using port 1337 for. As far as Windows 7 is concerned, I don't know if py2neo works there or not as I haven't tested it.